# python unix service library

Tags: python, unix, service, python-module

I have a command-line python app that is a service - i.e. it waits for connections and does stuff when asked, like webserver. There's `python-daemon` library for dealing with all the issues of detaching from the terminal, forking, etc. but I'd like to go a bit further - to have the program do the following:

1. Know if it's already running or not (by checking the PID file)
2. When called with 'start' option it should start the daemon if it's not running, or tell the PID of existing one and exit if running.
3. When called with 'stop' option it should kill the running instance if it exist, and clean the PID file.
4. When called with 'restart' option it should do 'stop', then 'start'
5. When called with 'status' option it should display the PID of running instance or nothing if it's not running.

If that looks like standard Unix service - that's exactly what I want. Is there a Python library that implements such pattern?

Comment: Maybe write a normal server and "daemonize" it with something like supervisord? http://supervisord.org/

Comment: @Peteris I thought about it, but it looks like an overkill - I need something very simple...

Comment: The requirements (1..5) seem too simple to require a library in light of POSIX functions already in PHP( [kill](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.posix-kill.php) ,exit,read,write,getpid, [pcntl_signal](http://us3.php.net/manual/es/function.pcntl-signal.php) ). Have the service listen for the signal TERM and call  exit().  Have a 2nd script to handle 2. start => start the service (shell, exec, fork etc). Save PID from getpid(),  to a file.  3. Kill($Pid_of_service). 4. stop + stop; 5. open, read pid from file.  So a wrapper script, instead of library, should do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this recipe. Works pretty good.

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

Comment: Also initd module seems to do the same: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/initd. Underdocumented, but seems to do the job.